# the definition of status "VerifyingService" output by "Get Current Status - Office 365 Service Communications API"

Tags: office365, office365api

I am trying to get O365 service status by using Office 365 Service Communication API and have 2 questions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference

Q1:
Is this status list at the following URL correct that responds with "Get Current Status"?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/view-service-health#status-definitions

Q2:
If Q1 is correct, there is no definition of "Verifying Service".
What does that mean?

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/view-service-health#status-definitions]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/view-service-health#status-definitions

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference#status-definitions]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference#status-definitions

Additional Info:
As a result of investigation, the difference between the status of API and M365 service health and common status are as follows

Microsoft 365 service health

- Investigation suspended

Office 365 Service Communications API reference

- VerifyingService
- ServiceOperational

Common Status

- Investigating
- ServiceDegradation
- ServiceInterruption
- RestoringService
- ExtendedRecovery
- ServiceRestored
- PostIncidentReportPublished
- FalsePositive